# Spacial Locality in loops

Tags: c, performance, loops, localityofreference

From what I understand, spacial locality has to do with nearby memory being used in the nearby future. However I was wondering if a loop is executed many times, does this lead to good spacial locality? Thanks in advance, and sorry if I'm hard to understand.

Comment: Without code, this question cannot be answered. Some loops may exhibit strong spatial locality, while other may exhibit none whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry for being too broad. Could you possibly give me an example of a type of loop that would be strong and one that would not?

Answer (score 5):

The number of iterations of a loop doesn't necessarily affect spatial locality. What the loop is *doing* does.

In practice, the key to spatial locality really has to do with cache lines.  In simple terms, a program that limits its accesses to a small number of *different* cache lines will exhibit more cache hits, and thus better performance.  A program that accesses a large number of different cache lines will encounter more cache misses, and thus lower peformance.

**Very good spatial locality:**

```
uint8_t g_array[2];

void test(void) {
    int i, a=0;
    for (i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        a += g_array[i % 2];      // Only ever accesses [0] or [1]
    }
}
```

This loop has very good spatial locality. The array is tiny, and the loop only ever accesses indices 0 or 1.

---

**Still good spatial locality:**

```
uint8_t g_array[CACHELINE_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (CACHELINE_SIZE)));

void test(void) {
    int i, a=0;
    for (i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        a += g_array[i % CACHELINE_SIZE];
    }
}
```

Here we have an array that is aligned to exactly one cache line.  Since the loop only accesses elements in that array, we can say it has good spatial locality - accesses will only ever touch that one cache line.

---

**Poor spatial locality:**

```
uint8_t g_array[RAND_MAX * CACHELINE_SIZE]
    __attribute__ ((aligned (CACHELINE_SIZE)));

void test(void) {
    int i, a=0;
    for (i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        int r = rand();
        a += g_array[(r*CACHELINE_SIZE) + (i%CACHELINE_SIZE)];
    }
}
```

This loop has remarkably poor spatial locality. It is accessing random locations all over memory.  Every loop iteration you can probably expect it to bounce to a different cache line. This will cause all kinds of cache misses, and the cache essentially becomes useless.

Comment: @user3277606 Personally, I think it would be a *good thing* to leave this question without an accepted answer yet. It may help bring other opinions to the table. There are a lot of smart people here (especially with the `performance` tag I've added), and I'd like to hear their opinions as well.

Comment: A good example to use is looping over a 2D array rows and columns vs. columns and rows vs. 4x4 squares.